# Definition of rotated panel sampling

Tags: self-study, sampling, survey-sampling

I am doing exercises and I come across a question that asks me to describe sampling with rotated panel.

What does rotated panel sampling mean?

Comment: Where did you come across the sampling? What is the motivation?

Comment: Hi. I found it in an exercise and I don't know what that is. I edit the question immediately.